# SimpleXmlElement->addAttribute() doesn't allow empty strings

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

### Description:

A call like addAttribute("attrname", "") results in
"PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Attribute name and value are required". In addition to the warning, the attribute is discarded.

### Reproduce code:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement("<img></img>");
$xml->addAttribute("src", "foo");
$xml->addAttribute("alt", "");
echo $xml->asXML()."\n";
?>
```

### Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<img src="foo" alt=""/>
```

### Actual result:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Attribute name and value are required in [...]/test.php on line 4
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<img src="foo"/>
```

this problem exists in PHP 5.2.1, but in PHP5.3.5 it works as I expect, but I can't change my php version(for some reason). Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

can you try by changing below line

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement("<img>");
```

and also you can try with below also

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');

    $doc = $xml->createElement('document');
    $doc = $xml->appendChild($doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute` says that the `value` parameter is optional, so you can try omitting that.  I didn't try using php 5.2.1, but 5.2.6 and 5.3 both work with the code you posted, and both emit warnings if you leave out the `value` argument (which confuses me wrt the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I don't have 5.2.1 at hand to test. It works on 5.3.6 though.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<img src="images/bg.png" alt="" />');
echo $xml->asXML();
```